# Why does the simplest TeX file give wrong page numbers and wrong page layout?

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{Hello}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents % I want to make the title and the TOC on the same page

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSection}

\end{document}
```

I want to make the title and the TOC on the same page, but there are two problems:

The first problem is the page numbers are wrong.

The second problem is the wrong page layout showed in the following screenshot:

[image]

[image]

What's the root cause?

Comment: LaTeX does not allow a page break after a section heading, put some text even if just `\mbox{}` in your sections. This is a duplicate I'll find the older question....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, +1, Why are the page numbering still wrong even if the page layout is ok?

Comment: @xmllmx What's wrong with the page numbers? If I run your MWE I get exactly what I'd expect: TOC on pages 1/2, content on page 3.

Comment: They are not wrong. In what way do you think they are I get all sections on page 3, and that shows in the toc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, The TOC shows Section 1 is on page 1, but it is actually on page 3. Please see my second picture.

Comment: run latex again, the section was on page 1 until the table of contents was generated on the second run. so will not show 3 until the third run

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I run xelatex three times, it's OK now! Thank you very much. It should require THREE times!!!

Comment: twice is not enough, as I said.